# How to make image scrolling effect inside other image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollview

I want to make something similar to this, to promote my sites in a scrolling effect just like in this [page](http://preview.themeforest.net/item/fwrd-music-band-musician-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/12087239)

I found that the image from the computer is just an image:

[image]

and site scrolling inside is an image also:

[image]

So my question is, how to make another image scroll inside that computer PC, like on the original site I provided, maybe some JS?

This is similar [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/h5Lrq9zy/) i found:

**HTML**:

```
<ul id="scroller">
<li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPcRz.jpg" width="400" 
height="1000"></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**:

```
    (function($) {
        $(function() { //on DOM ready
            $("#scroller").simplyScroll({
                customClass: 'vert',
                orientation: 'vertical',
                auto: true,
                manualMode: 'end',
                frameRate: 8,
                speed: 3
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

and CSS:

```
/* Container DIV */
    .simply-scroll {
        width: 400px;
        height: 1000px;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }
```

but how to make this image inside the PC image, and move up and down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what all you need.

```css
.computer-empty {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 540px;
}
.computer-screen {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    height: 247px;
    width: 445px;
    left: 50px;
    top: 20px;
}
.screen-landing {
    left: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 6s;
    -o-transition: all 6s;
    -ms-transition: all 6s;
    -moz-transition: all 6s;
    -webkit-transition: all 6s;
}
.screen-landing:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: -1036px;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto\9;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
.computer-empty img.computer {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-align-center computer-empty">
                
                <a target="_blank" href="http://irontemplates.com/demos/redirect.php?theme=The%20Rise" class="">
                <div class="computer-screen">
                    <div class="screen-landing">
                        <img src="http://fwrd.irontemplates.com/home/img/the_rise.jpg" alt="demo - the rise">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img class="computer" src="http://fwrd.irontemplates.com/home/img/computer.jpg" alt="computer">
                </a>
                <h1>The Rise</h1>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the best solution but the only one I can think of right now:

1. You could edit the picture of the computer, cut the screen off, and make it transparent.
2. Make 2 divs, one inside the other.
3. First, the bigger one will contain a picture of the computer.
4. Second one will fill exactly the empty space in the picture of the computer, where the screen would be.
5. Make sure to add `overflow: scroll;` in your stylesheet for the inner div.

It would look something like this:

HTMl:

```
<div>
    <img src="path to your picture of computer">
    <div class="img-box">
        <img src="path to your picture of inside screen">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-box{
        width: ???;
        height: ???;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
```

Now I am aware that this solution will be hard to make responsive, but it is the only thing I can think of right now.

Comment: Thanks, will look your soltuion too.