# How to add a mouse over scroll effect to an image within an image

Tags: html, css

Can anyone assist me with the below coding? I am trying to add an image of a monitor with another image within the monitor that has an auto scrolling effect on mouseover.

I have tried the following from this post:
[How to make image scrolling effect inside other image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46321939/how-to-make-image-scrolling-effect-inside-other-image)

I did post there too then only noticed I should have posted if I had a solution so I re-posted as a fresh post.

CSS Code I am using:

```
.computer-empty {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 540px;
}
.computer-screen {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 265px;
    width: 480px;
    left: 30px;
    top: 20px;

}
.screen-landing {
    left: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 6s;
    -o-transition: all 6s;
    -ms-transition: all 6s;
    -moz-transition: all 6s;
    -webkit-transition: all 6s;
}
.screen-landing:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: -1036px;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
.computer-empty img.computer {
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML Code im using:

```
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.safidrivingschool.co.uk" class="">

<div class="computer-screen">

<div class="screen-landing">

<img src="http://www.webnificent.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/graphics/safidrivingschool_capture.png" alt="Safi Driving School">

</div>
</div>

<img class="computer" src="http://www.webnificent.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/graphics/apple_montior.png" alt="computer">

</a>
</div>
```

If I set position to absolute on .computer-screen, both images line up correctly but then the scroll effect won't work.  If I set it as relative, the scroll effect works but then the images sit on top of one another.

See this link: **Example: https://webnificent.co.uk/web-design/**

A solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was pretty fiddly, but hopefully this will help?

**Let me know if you have issues with this at all!**

```css
.computer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    width: 540px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.computer-empty {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 540px;
}

.computer-screen {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 260px;
  width: 470px;
  left: 35px;
  top: 21px;

}

.screen-landing {
  left: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 6s;
  -o-transition: all 6s;
  -ms-transition: all 6s;
  -moz-transition: all 6s;
  -webkit-transition: all 6s;
}

.screen-landing:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -1036px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;

}

.computer-empty img.computer {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <a target="_blank" href="http://www.safidrivingschool.co.uk" class="">

   <div class="computer-screen">
     <div class="screen-landing">
       <img src="http://www.webnificent.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/graphics/safidrivingschool_capture.png" alt="Safi Driving School">
     </div>
   </div>

   <img class="computer" src="http://www.webnificent.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/graphics/apple_montior.png" alt="computer">

 </a>
```

See it on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s1n3dxcL/)

Just a suggestion, it might be easier to use a computer screen with a totally black screen, such as this: [Imac with Black Screen](https://images.app.goo.gl/i4gPTyEMEHqCfaww8), just because in my example I had to fiddle with `left`, `top`, `width` and `height` just to make it fit into the white empty box of your computer screen. If you didn't have a specific box to fit into, you wouldn't have to worry about this & could just plonk your animated image scroll in the middle of the screen!

Just a thought!

Comment: EGC you are a legend, thank you very much for the quick response and time to working it out.  Much appreciated, and point taken with regards to the black screen.

Comment: Nw! I think the key thing you needed was z-index https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp . Mark it as accepted if it solved your issue? :)

Comment: Hey EGC, I noticed that the outer image is responsive but the inner image isn't, dont suppose you have a solution to make the inner image response so it shows on all devices.

Comment: Hm, when you say responsive, do you mean containing the inner image in the outer image is all messed up?

Comment: I suppose you could have a look at this? It's half-way through, so maybe you can fill in my blanks. I'm using `@media-query`'s and have changed your nesting a little bit: https://jsfiddle.net/ehyw0zrm/1/

Comment: Exactly, the inner image gets messed up and doesn't stay within the outer image.  I'll have at the link you given.  Many thx.